# sumar, multiplicar, elevar vertor por una matriz

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, usecase

Como le hago para poder mostrar los siguientes resultados
dependiendo lo que decida el usuario
elija sumar, multiplicar, elevar o salir
se debe mostrar solo el resultado de las operaciones
la imagen muestra como hay que obtener el resultado y como se debe de ver al ejecutar el programa
[image: ejemplo de como es la forma para obtener los resultados]

int opcion =0;

```
    {
      opcion = Integer.parseInt ( JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Selecciona una de las opciones: \n+"
              + " 1.- Sumar \n"
              +"2.- Multiplicar\n "
              + "3.- Elevar \n "
              + "4.-SALIR"));
    }
      int arreglo1[]= {2,4,5};
      int arreglo2[]= {8,2,5}{4,2,6}{1,4,7};
      int resultado[] = new int[6];
           switch(opcion)
                {
                case 1: //sumar
                 for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                 resultado[i] = arreglo1[i] + arreglo2[i];
                }
                for(int i=0; i<resultado.length; i++){
                System.out.print(resultado[i] + " | ");
                }
                break;
                case 2://multiplicar
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                 resultado[i] = arreglo1[i] * arreglo2[i];
                }
                for(int i=0; i<resultado.length; i++){
                System.out.print(resultado[i] + " | ");
                }
                break;
                case 3://Elevar
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                 resultado[i] = arreglo1[i] ^ arreglo2[i];
                }
                for(int i=0; i<resultado.length; i++){
                System.out.print(resultado[i] + " | ");
                }
                break;
                case 4://salir
                         System.exit(0);
                    break;
                    
                    default:
           }while(opcion >= 1 && opcion <= 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

Holaa, bueno tu codigo esta casi bien, ahora tienes otro problema, estas intentando esto: int arreglo2[]= {8,2,5}{4,2,6}{1,4,7}; que hasta donde se, es imposible, deberías crear otros arreglos, y luego en el for estas intentando ir mas espacios de los que hay, has hecho un arreglo de 3 espacios y tratas de recorrer 6, tenes que cambiarlo a 3, lo probé funciona correctamente

```
int arreglo1[]= {2,4,5};
int arreglo2[]= {8,2,5}; //{4,2,6}{1,4,7};
int arreglo3[]= {4,2,6};
int arreglo4[]= {1,4,7};

int resultado1[] = new int[3];
int resultado2[] = new int[3];

switch(opcion){
case 1: //sumar
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //tu codigo recorria 6 espacio
resultado1[i] = arreglo1[i] + arreglo2[i];
resultado2[i] = arreglo3[i] + arreglo4[i];
}
for(int i=0; i<resultado1.length; i++){
System.out.print(resultado1[i] + " | ");
}
System.out.println("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < resultado2.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(resultado2[i] + " | ");
}
break;
```

Te muestro el caso de sumar y luego seria lo mismo para los otros casos solo hay que cambiarle los signos por el de multiplicar y elevar y listo, por cierto no entendí muy bien la imagen...

Comment: Lo primero que tienes que saber es cómo calcular a mano las operaciones de las que hablas entre un vector y una matriz

Comment: Hola Japv, el comentario es para mi o para geovanni? no entiendo bien esto de los comentarios, he agarrado el código de la pregunta y le cambie algunas cosas para que funcione, como seria la forma correcta de hacerlo? es que a mi me funciono bien